# Extract line number of a file which is having a non zero value before a specified string

Tags: grep, string, numbering

I'm having a file which contains following data

```
1. verification: 10 passed 0 failed
2. verification: 10 passed 0 failed
3. verification: 10 passed 1 failed
4. verification: 10 passed 3 failed
5. verification: 10 passed 0 failed
```

I want to know the line numbers of 3 and 4.

Comment: This: `egrep "^3.+" <FILE>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file is called `in.txt`, then:-

```
awk '$5>0 {print $0; }' in.txt
```

will give you:-

```
3. verification: 10 passed 1 failed
4. verification: 10 passed 3 failed
```

I've made the assumption the the line numbers (1-5) is part of the file.  If it isn't change the `$5` to `$4`.

If the line number is part of the file and you want to just print it without the dot:-

```
awk '$5>0 {sub(/\./,"",$1); print $1 }' in.txt
```

which gives:-

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU grep`, you can use `lookbehind`:

```
$ grep -P '(?<!0) failed' file 
3. verification: 10 passed 1 failed
4. verification: 10 passed 3 failed
```

Or a shorter version of `awk`:

```
$ awk '$5 > 0' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that i'm not printint real numbers, but the first number in the line until the dot.

With **sed**:

```
 cat inputfile.txt | sed  '/ 0 failed$/d ; s/\..*//'
```

With **grep and sed**:

```
 cat inputfile.txt | grep -v ' 0 failed$' | sed 's/\..*//'
```

Output:

```
3
4
```